# Response Header status code is not valid from Laravel Response in phpdesktop-chrome-57-php-7.13-rc

Tags: php, laravel, google-chrome, phpdesktop

Hi I am using **phpdesktop-chrome-57-php-7.13-rc** and facing some very weired issues with Laravel and raw php.

On every error status code it is returning, 200 have a look

[image]

its a simple Laravel Login the result status code should be 422 but it is showing 200 but in Response Headers it's showing the correct information.

In request Headers, it always shows Provisional Headers are shown and there is no response data.

Please help me fixing this issue

Tried everything by returning headers in response, response with only error code etc, but no luck. Even when exception came the result remain same.

Have a look to my code

```
return response(["Unable to Process Command"],422);
```

Comment: Could you show us the code that's involved in handling the request and sending the response?

Comment: @PtrTon added code in question too.

Comment: From what I know the chrome debugging tool will show the "Provisional headers are shown" message for outgoing requests which have yet to return a response, but I'm not sure that's the case here. With the information you provided there's not much to go on.

Comment: @PtrTon I am referring to particular case with PhpDesktop-chrome-57 

Else things are working pretty fine. issue is only when it runs in above stated particular environment